# “adb” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: android, macos

I faced the following problem: when I try to make a RN project as in [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started), I have the next window: `“adb” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.`

Yes, I know that when I have such window I should open the app in finder, click the right button of the mouse and then click "open".
But in this situation I cannot do it, as there's no way to open `adb` in finder, so, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In macOS Ventura 13.3.1, open “System Settings” → “Privacy & Security” → “Security”.

Under “Allow apps downloaded from:” click “Allow Anyway” on adb, then try again.

Comment: Not listed. I suspect it's not notarized or something.

Comment: In macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, this still works

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had to restart my terminal before I could see the new effect.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer didn't work for me.

I searched for adb like this

```
which adb
```

Then terminal told me the path to the adb executable, so I opened that location

```
open /usr/local/bin
```

Then right-clicked on it, and chose open, and then I did have the option to open the app instead of just move to trash.